# Building a SharePoint 2010 RTM Environment

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm looking to build a SharePoint 2010 RTM environment and I'm wondering if there's a guide out there for doing so.  I have 4 VMs (AD, WEB, SQL, IDX) to use to build the proper environment.

Answer (score 1):

There absolutely is.  I assume that you have the Sharepoint 2010 RTM disk or image handy?  If so, pop up the autorun screen where you have the option to install the prerequisites, the server, etc.  It should look like [this](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_14GIHlDK-y0/Swa9Nxrc--I/AAAAAAAAAko/pTogDRMMyhQ/s1600-h/image[100].png).

On this same menu, look for the option "Read Installation Guide".  You will find everything you need related to the RTM install and environment setup in that document.